# los cambios no se actualizan en la base de datos usando entity framework 6

Tags: c#, windows-forms, entity-framework-6

en mi solución integré con el EF la base de datos, puedo leer las entradas y "modificarlas" pero al usar `entidad.savechange();` no da error ni nada, cierro la solución e ingreso en la DB y los cambios **no se ven reflejados**, uso un archivo mdf para la DB.
mi funcion para guardar

```
        public static void Guardar(anime ge1)
        {
            using (var db = new AnimesDatabaseEntities())
            {
                var upanime = db.anime.SingleOrDefault(x => x.id_Anime == ge1.id_Anime);
                if (upanime.Nombre_anim != ge1.Nombre_anim)
                { upanime.Nombre_anim = ge1.Nombre_anim; }
                if (upanime.Pagina_anim != ge1.Pagina_anim)
                { upanime.Pagina_anim = ge1.Pagina_anim; }
                if (upanime.Descripcion_anim != ge1.Descripcion_anim)
                { upanime.Descripcion_anim = ge1.Descripcion_anim; }
                if (upanime.Capitulos_anim != ge1.Capitulos_anim)
                { upanime.Capitulos_anim = ge1.Capitulos_anim; }
                if (upanime.EnEmision_anim != ge1.EnEmision_anim)
                { upanime.EnEmision_anim = ge1.EnEmision_anim; }
                if (upanime.Visto_anim != ge1.Visto_anim)
                { upanime.Visto_anim = ge1.Visto_anim; }
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

de antemano muchas gracias por la ayuda, si es necesario algo mas lo agregare.

edit:
asi esta definida automáticamente mi clase, use primero la DB no la cree por código

```
using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    
    public partial class anime
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public anime()
        {
            this.anime_has_genero = new HashSet<anime_has_genero>();
        }
    
        public int id_Anime { get; set; }
        public string Nombre_anim { get; set; }
        public string Pagina_anim { get; set; }
        public string Descripcion_anim { get; set; }
        public int Capitulos_anim { get; set; }
        public string EnEmision_anim { get; set; }
        public string Visto_anim { get; set; }
    
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<anime_has_genero> anime_has_genero { get; set; }
    }
}
```

aun con los cambios sigo sin poder actualizar los cambios en la DB

al usar entidad.Entry(nombre).state confirmo que el estado a cambiado a modificado, no se en que parte podra estar el error.

Comment: Al escribir esto "EntityState.Detached" que quisiste hacer?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/es-ES/b4b350ba-b0d5-464d-8656-8c117d55b2af/problema-al-modificar-en-entity-framework?forum=vcses tenia el mismo error de este foro, al aplicar el cambio pude solucionarlo, anque sigo sin poder reflejar los cambios en la DB antes solo usaba el savechange en vez de todo el if que tiene debajo el codigo

Comment: Mira.. lei muy por arriba.. y me parece que te creaste un problema que no tenias para solucionar un problema que no se cual era.. y copiaste codigo sin entenderlo.. al hacer detached, EF deja de seguir esos objetos, con lo cual no va a grabar nada... como solucion, parece mala....

Comment: tienes razon, la parte del codigo 
`var local = entidad.Set<clase>()
                .Local
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.id== ani.id);
                if (local != null)
                entidad.Entry(local).State = EntityState.Detached;`
no es necesaria, fue por el anterior, aun asi solo usando el savechange no me dio ningun error, pero tampoco me actualiza el archivo de la DB.

Comment: leí la documentacion un poco y me di cuuenta de lo que mencionas, pero asi solo obtengo un " Attaching an entity of type 'Modelo.Otros' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values."

Comment: Podes contarnos donde obtenes ese error??? porque ahi esta tu problema.. tambien, como esta definido tu modelo...

Comment: en la error list en el visual studio, al ejecutar para la ejecucion mostrandome ese error en la linea de codigo

Comment: en que linea? en que metodo? donde ocurre? nos falta informacion.. y vos estas tratando de solucionar algo sin entender EF :(

Comment: no puedo poner actualmente el error debido a que no me encuentro en mi computador, no se como ilustrar mejor el error, creo que va a ser mejor compartir mi repositorio para que lo puedan revisar?

Comment: Pero ahi no hay ni una pk, ni se llama id... y si pusiste desde genero1 hasta genero15 (lo acabo de notar) tu db, esta mal!

Comment: mi estimado, tienes razon, para empezar esto es por hobbie, y estudiar por mis propios medios, y un cercano me recomendo usar el EF debido a que ya tenia la DB de prueba armada, ese es el archivo generado automaticamente

Comment: Y  si ese es el archivo generado; como tu clase busca por iD??? Si ahi no hay id??? tu codigo, no se condice con tu clase, o tenes multiples clases (eso es una parcial class)... aunque EF te soluciona un monton de problemas, tambien te genera otros si no entendes perfectamente como funciona (como aca).. tu DB, tiene que estar en tercera forma normal para ser correcta....

Comment: y ahora cual seria el problema?

Comment: `        public static BindingList<Animes> TraerAnimes()
        {
            anime_db = new CapaDatos.AnimesDatabaseEntities();
            anime_db.Animes.Load();
            listanimes = anime_db.Animes.Local.ToBindingList();
            return anime_db.Animes.Local.ToBindingList();
        }`
todo lo hago desde una binding list, que es el unico acceso que tengo a la DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este código no te hace falta:

```
if (ani.IdAnime > 0)
{
    var local = entidad.Set<clase>()
                       .Local
                       .FirstOrDefault(x => x.id== ani.id);

   if (local != null)
       entidad.Entry(local).State = EntityState.Detached;

       entidad.Entry(ani).State = EntityState.Modified;
       entidad.SaveChanges();
}
else
{
    entidad.clase.Add(ani);
}
```

Para actualizar lo único que debes hacer es:

```
entidad.SaveChanges();
```

El **EntityFramework** hace un seguimiento a todos los cambios que se hacen en él dígase operaciones de adición, eliminación o actualización, y a cada tipo de operación le hace una marca correspondiente, es decir cambia su estado, de este modo sabe que entidad fue añadida, eliminada o modificada, pero hay un tipo de cambio de estado especial llamado **Detached**, el cual le indica al **EntityFramework** que no "haga caso" de cualquier cambio que se haya hecho, por tanto el **EntityFramework** al encontrar una entidad cuyo estado sea **Detached** pués no hará nada, es decir las entidades que tengan el estado **Detached** no se guardarán, no se modificarán, y no se eliminarán, simplemente serán obviadas por el **EntityFramework**.

Tu código final quedaría como:

```
public static void Guardar(clase ani)
{
   using DatabaseEntities entidad = new DatabaseEntities()
   {
      clase _update = entidad.clase.Where(x => x.id == ani.id).FirstOrDefault();

      _update.Nombre = ani.Nombre;
      _update.Descripcion = ani.Descripcion;
      _update.Pagina = ani.Pagina;
      _update.Genero1 = ani.Genero1;
      _update.Genero2 = ani.Genero2;
      _update.Genero3 = ani.Genero3;
      _update.Genero4 = ani.Genero4;
      _update.Genero5 = ani.Genero5;
      _update.Genero6 = ani.Genero6;
      _update.Genero7 = ani.Genero7;
      _update.Genero8 = ani.Genero8;
      _update.Genero9 = ani.Genero9;
      _update.Genero10 = ani.Genero10;
      _update.Genero11 = ani.Genero11;
      _update.Genero12 = ani.Genero12;
      _update.Genero13 = ani.Genero13;
      _update.Genero14 = ani.Genero14;
      _update.Genero15 = ani.Genero15;
      _update.CantCap = ani.CantCap;
      _update.Visto = ani.Visto;
      _update.EnEmision = ani.EnEmision;
    
      entidad.SaveChanges();
   }
}
```

Comment: al tenerlo de esa manera me arrojaba el error Attaching an entity of type failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value, al aplicar ese if me dio solución, al leer un poco la documentación me di cuenta de lo que dices, pero aún así no me aplica los cambios.

Comment: @andresfelipe cual es la PK de esa entidad? estas cambiando la PK y agregando una PK que ya existe???

Comment: la pk es la id que se usa en todos los objeto ani la tiene para identificarlo, en este caso seria para hacer un update

Comment: @gbianchi realice varios cambio pero sigo sin poder que se actualicen los cambios rrealizados en la DB